# Error in including a Global Vector when used in multiple files

Tags: c++

```
// Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"
#include "second.cpp"
#include <vector>

int main(){
  global = 10;
  ip.push_back("TestTest");
  std::cout << global << std::endl;
  TestClass t;
  t.print();
}

//common.h
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H
#include <vector> 
#include <string>
extern int global;
extern std::vector<std::string> ip ; 
#endif

// second.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"

int global;

class TestClass{

  public:
    void print();};
void TestClass::print(){
  global++;
  std::cout << "Global: "<<global << std::endl;
  std::cout << "IP String: "<<ip[0] << std::endl;
}

// Console Error
ubuntu:deleteme$ g++ main.cpp
/tmp/ccoJpYRl.o: In function `TestClass::print()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `ip'
/tmp/ccoJpYRl.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `ip'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The above works when I am just using with the `int global` variable. However when I added a vector `ip` to the `common.h` I am getting the showed error.

This seems like a elemental thing but couldn't get an answer.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define the `std::vector<std::string>`.
With extern you just declard that it's global but defined in another place.
You should add the definition under your `int global` in `second.cpp`

```
// second.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"

int global;
std::vector<std::string> ip;

class TestClass{
```

As an aside, you shouldn't use globals.

Comment: ahh!! Stupid. Thanks. I love Stackoverflow! Got an answer in less than 5 mins.